# App rejected : When file sharing is enabled, the entire Documents folder is used for file sharing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have enabled `UIFileSharingEnabled` in the application plist file. But is it possible to show only particular files. like show only `PDF` files.

**Problem**

Recently My application is rejected due to below reason

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:pathArray toFile:[self itemArchivePath]];
```

> When file sharing is enabled, the entire Documents folder is used for
>   file sharing. Files that are not intended for user access via the file
>   sharing feature should be stored in another part of your application's
>   bundle. If your application does not require the file sharing feature,
>   the UIFileSharingEnabled key in the Info.plist should not be set to
>   true.

This issue comes when i use the FaceBook SDK.

```
 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        [FBSettings setDefaultAppID:FACEBOOK_APP_ID];
        [FBAppEvents activateApp];
    }
```

**Note : I observe that facebook sdk generating one json file. So is there any way to not to show that file?**

[image: File Share]

```
                                            data:image/png;base64,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
```

Comment: There is no way to do this AFAIK. Facebook has no good reason to store their json in the Documents folder, it should go in the ApplicationData folder instead. Did you check to see if they have an update that might solve this issue?

Comment: This question is still valid after 21 months?